# GIMP: Set All New Images to Default Transparent Background?

Tags: gimp

Is there a way in GIMP to set an option so that all new images are created with a transparent background?

Currently, when I ^N (New Image), I have to click "Advanced Options", then open the dialogue "Fill" box and select "Transparent".  A real timewaster.

Any help?

Comment: Stack Overflow is for questions about programming; software usage is handled at SuperUser.

Comment: See https://superuser.com/questions/1360958/gimp-set-all-new-images-to-default-transparent-background